# Get selected Item Text from "MetroListView"

Tags: c#, metroframework

how can I get a selected Item vom "MetroListView?

Previously I had implemented this with a Listbox

```
StarcDevice = listBox2.GetItemText(listBox2.SelectedItem);
```

But with MetroListView I don't have such a Method

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get first element from selected items and get text with `Text` property.

```
StarcDevice = listBox2.SelectedItems[0]?.Text;
```

For fast search MetroListView members you can check here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/jj681324(v=msdn.10)

Comment: Doesn't work. I cannot use "FirstOrDefault()" with SelectedItems

Comment: @TheMan yep, you're right, not checked it, fix answer

Answer (score 0):

For all people with the same problem.

Done it like the following

```
StarcDevice = metroListViewSTARCDevice.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
```